# Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable - Error

Tags: bluetooth, raspbian-jessie, arduino

I am trying to connect a HC-05 Bluetooth Module (connected to Arduino Uno) to my Raspberry Pi 3 in the hopes of achieving bluetooth communication between the two to send data from the Uno to the Pi.

Trying to use Bluetoothctl to pair, connect and trust the HC-05 device seems to fail for me.

```
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 LegacyPairing: yes
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 RSSI: -43

[bluetooth]# pair 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1
Attempting to pair with 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 Connected: yes
Request PIN code
[agent] Enter PIN code: 1234
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 Connected: no

[bluetooth]# connect 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1
Attempting to connect to 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 Connected: no

[bluetooth]# trust 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 Trusted: yes
Changing 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 trust succeeded
```

Here is the info prompt.

```
[bluetooth]# info 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1
Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1
        Name: HC-05
        Alias: HC-05
        Class: 0x001f00
        Paired: yes
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: no
        LegacyPairing: yes
        UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
```

Specifically the error I am getting is "**Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable**"

I am not sure how to get pass this error and I am unable to complete my project without confirming a linked bluetooth signal between the two microprocessors.

Thanks, Aditya

Answer (score 7):

You do not need to `connect` with Bluetoothctl. With Bluetoothctl, use exactly most commands as you show; then after `pair`, leave this window but not close. Open new terminal and use

```
rfcomm bind rfcomm0 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1
```

But note: there is still no connection at this stage. To make real connection, use something to connect to your new serial port, like

```
screen /dev/rfcomm0 9600,cs8,-parenb,-cstopb,-hupcl  #  use ^a, k to exit.
```

Try send some chars with keyboard. After 2-3 seconds, you find your HC-05 connected by its LED. And look at your first window where Bluetoothctl runs. It will show that your HC-05 is connected.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! Note for others, you can quickly check if you are getting data (assuming your bt device is just always streaming) with cat: `cat /dev/rfcomm0 `. If you see data there you should be able to communicate with the device using a library like pyserial.

Answer (score 3):

Try to install the `blueman` pack using `sudo apt-get install blueman`, or, if you have it installed, try

```
sudo apt remove blueman
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

After one of this processes, run `blueman` or go to the `Menu > Preferences > Bluetooth Mananger`, then, search `HC-05`, add it to the *Trust List*, insert the *password* (normally `1234` or `0000`) and connect it by clicking `Configure`.

If the problem persists, the problem is with the `HC-05` module, try to connect it to an *Android*, if it doesn't connect, you will need to buy a new one.