# Troubles connecting raspberry and OBD2 through bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w, debian, bluez

I try to connect my pi zero W to OBD2 module through bluetoooth. My pi is connected to my 4G iphone wifi and I communicate with it through ssh.

I used bluetoothctl and can't connect when running `connect 01:23:45:67:89:BA`.
I got the following error message `Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable`

When also running `connection = obd.OBD('/dev/rfcomm1')` I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/coco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/obd/obd.py", line 63, in __init__
    self.__connect(portstr, baudrate, protocol,
  File "/home/coco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/obd/obd.py", line 85, in __connect
    self.interface = ELM327(port, baudrate, protocol,
  File "/home/coco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/obd/elm327.py", line 146, in __init__
    if not self.set_baudrate(baudrate):
  File "/home/coco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/obd/elm327.py", line 294, in set_baudrate
    return self.auto_baudrate()
  File "/home/coco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/obd/elm327.py", line 324, in auto_baudrate
    response = self.__port.read(1024)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 577, in read
    raise SerialException(
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

I tried `sudo rfcomm bind rfcomm1 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1` as shown here:
[Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable - Error](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82173/failed-to-connect-org-bluez-error-notavailable-error/82184)

PS : screen command also doesn't work, my screen is blinking when launching the command

Thank you in advance for your help,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's zero interest in it.